# Variable in Select Statement

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Here is the  query I have built to derive tech number. I can't get it to work. I get this error message:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.

The query:

```
declare @TechNum int =
    (Select Case When  CF_Technician='David' Then 9 When
        CF_Technician='David N' Then 9 When 
        CF_Technician='David Nunez' Then 9 When 
        CF_Technician='Joe  Nicholson' Then 8 When 
        CF_Technician='Joe Nicholson' Then 8 When 
        CF_Technician='Josh Fogleman' Then 7 When 
        else 0
        End
     From OptimazationItems)

Select  
    ItemID,  
    TechNum=@TechNum
From
    OptimazationItems
```

What is wrong? Why can't I use a variable in the select statement? What is the best way to accomplish this?

I know I can create another view and join it afterwards. Is there a way to do it in one query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable, but you have assign to it a subquery that returns **at most one row**. The subquery you assign obviously returns **more than one row**. Run the subquery in isolation, you'll see that it returns more than one row.

Rewrite the subquery to only return (at most) one row. You'll probably want to add a `WHERE` clause or a `SELECT TOP 1` + `ORDER BY some_column` to select a specific row.

---

It looks from the comments that you didn't understand what I was saying. What you probably meant to write is the following.

```
SELECT  
    ItemID,  
    TechNum=CASE CF_Technician
            WHEN 'David'          THEN 9 
            WHEN 'David N'        THEN 9 
            WHEN 'David Nunez'    THEN 9
            WHEN 'Joe  Nicholson' THEN 8
            WHEN 'Joe Nicholson'  THEN 8
            WHEN 'Josh Fogleman'  THEN 7
            ELSE 0
            END
FROM
    OptimazationItems
```

You cannot write this select statement using a variable.

Comment: for example. Can you give more specific example

Comment: @atlasbeencounter You assign to `@TechNum` the resultaat of a subquery. Copy/paste that subquery, and execute it. Tell me the number of rows it returns. If it's more than one, explain to me how you see this being assigned to a single variabele that can only contain one value.

Comment: @AtlasBeencounter Updated my answer with the query you are looking for.